# Race Condition across collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, race-condition

I have two collections that are interdependent and when update requests are received simultaneously for the respective collections the operations (Check for existence and get relevant values) are interleaved and leaves the documents in inconsistent state.

Among threads we can use synchronisation controls, but how do we handle across process in distributed systems.

**example:** Order head and Order line are different collections and each has its own set of endpoints. When head-item is updated all the relevant line items's associated fields gets updated. When a line-item is entered it checks for the head-item to get necessary fields, otherwise it saves the necessary fields as blanks. My problem in particular is when head-item and line-item is getting added by two different processes at the same time, the operations for checking the DB and saving into the DB are interleaved.

Comment: Your question is vague, but MongoDB supports transactions on MongoDB 4.0+. If this isn't possible, then maybe you can take advantage of Mongo's atomic operations like $addToSet.

Comment: @RobertSeaman I added a example. Hope this explains the problem i am facing. BTW, I am using mongo 3.6

Comment: This sounds like a common race condition problem, rather than MongoDB? Could you use something like apache's zookeeper so each process can take a lock for the particular operation?

Comment: @RobertSeaman Could help me with some resources on how to do with zookeeper.

Comment: Zookeeper might be a bit of an overkill for what you want to do. Can you reference the head id (ObjectID) in every line item? I think the problem is that you're updating the line items with 2 processes, when you could just use a reference to the relevant head object. This will also save on duplication.